# Formatting json objects for display in a node js console app

Tags: node.js, console

I have a node js console app that saves data in a json file. I want to be able to format the data and display it nicely on the console. I've used prettyjson, json-nice, etc. but thay all seem to work only when there is one json object in the file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` but you need to specify the amount of spacing.

See here for a complete reference: [MDN - JSON.stringify Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
let test =  [{
   "deviceTypeID": 232,
   "deviceTypeName": "Liebert NX UPS",
   "deviceId": 1174,
   "deviceName": "UPSA",
   "location": "UPS ROOM",
   "ipAddress": "192.168.2.5",
   "portNumber": 502,
   "deviceAddress": 1,
   "protocol": "Modbus",
   "bmsAddress": 110,
   "isBmsConfigured": true,
   "bmsPassword": 1234,
   "KwRating": "0"
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 3));
```

If you want to save it to a file instead, you can do something like below:

```
    let fs = require('fs');
    let jsonObject = {...};

    fs.writeFile(('./myJsonFile.json'), JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 3), (err) => {
        if(err) logError(err);
    });
```